# Caffe Build Error in Windows 10

Tags: gcc, cmake, windows-10, caffe

I'm trying to build Caffe in Windows 10 following instructions [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/windows). I have installed all the prerequisites and dependencies. But I'm getting following error.

```
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-
3.9/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:51 (message):
 The C compiler "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe" is not able to compile a simple test
 program.

 It fails with the following output:

  Change Dir: C:/Caffe/caffe/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

 Run Build Command:"C:/Ninja/ninja.exe" "cmTC_6595e"

 [1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles\cmTC_6595e.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj

 FAILED: CMakeFiles/cmTC_6595e.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj

 C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_6595e.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj -c
 testCCompiler.c

 ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

 CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
 CMakeLists.txt:18 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Caffe/caffe/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Caffe/caffe/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
ERROR: Configure failed
```

[Caffe Build Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOLkx.png)

I searched for a solution and tried different things but nothing could solve the problem. Any help with this regard is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out. It was a problem with the C Compiler in my computer - gcc. I reinstalled the compiler and following two lines to CMakeList.txt file according to [this solution](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/5248#issuecomment-279226614),

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "C:/MinGW/bin/g++.exe")
```